# How write unit test case for below in jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

```
 public writeValue(item): void {
  
        if(item.length> 0)
        for(let i=0;i<=item.length-1;i++)
        {
            this.salesDivisionTagSet.push(item[i]);
        }
```

iam new to angular testing i am not able to write unit test cases for the above because of this coverage is not increasing can somebody help me with this .

Comment: Did you tried anything to write and facing problem into it?

Comment: What you have written so far? If you new to unit test cases the I advise you to learn first,

Answer (score 0):

Your test case would be something like below.

```
it("should push when item when list is selected", () => {
    component.salesDivision = mockSalesDivision
    spyOn(component.salesDivisionTagSet, "push");
    component.writeValue([9,1]);
    expect(component.salesDivisionTagSet.push).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

As your code says item can be array or simple value. Above test case is covered for the type of array. You need to write another test case where value will be non array like below.

```
component.writeValue(78);
expect(component.salesDivisionTagSet.push).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```